# Run Time Error 9 - Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to return to the first page in the workbook.

```vb
Sub OpenMenu()
   ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+m

   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Macros").Activate
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Macros").Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a Worksheet named "Macros"?

Comment: Perhaps you have more than one workbook open.

Comment: If you don't have "Macros" sheet, then macros will fail. If you need just first sheet (no matter what name it has), then use just `Sheets(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling it by name, since you want teh first one you can call it by it's index:

```
Sub OpenMenu()
   ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+m

   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```